# Cached view without observe

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the views cached without explicitly observing it or if caching is tightly coupled to there being observers.

Now my use case is definitely out of the ordinary and not the intended one. I'm not using MST reactively but rather in a request/response kind of way. So in my response function I get some (possibly expensive) views from the tree (to which I hold a global reference). Would there be a sane way to incorporate caching into such a model or would it just be too far away from MST's main use case?

I built minimal example that shows a case in which I'd like to have caching: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/perfect-peripheral (click on view logs on the left)

Answer (score -1):

Uhm, not sure but MST caches by default any view because it observes it internally :)

Comment: Do you have some source for that? I think that's actually not the case (see this comment https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/409#issuecomment-332984904)